# cannot find class at runtime in Maven

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm new to Maven and I'm trying to learn how to use it. My dependency looks like this:

```
<dependency>
         <groupId>com</groupId>
         <artifactId>phidgets</artifactId>
         <version>2.1</version>
         <scope>system</scope>
         <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/phidget21.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

I have installed the dependency using `mvn install:file-install`. After that, the project compiles fine with `mvn compile`. However, when I tried `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="myApp"`, it cannot find the classes in `phidget21.jar` and throws `ClassNotFoundException`.

Any pointer would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### The short answer, solves your problem but is not best practice

You need to configure the exec plugin to use `system` scoped dependencies, it uses `runtime` by default.

You can either configure it in the POM or use `-Dexec.classpathScope=system` at the command line.

That being said, `mvn install:install-file` is completely redundant in your case since `system`-scoped dependencies are never resolved through the repository.

### The right way to do it:

Since you have declared being a Maven novice, I **strongly** recommend that you stay clear of `system`-scoped dependencies unless absolutely necessary; they make your builds less portable.

Your invocation of `mvn install:install-file` means that you can dispense with the `<scope>` and `<systemPath>` tags altogether and it'll work as you intend. Maven will resolve your dependency through the repository.

Comment: I have tried getting rid of <scope> and <systemPath> but it doesn't compile at all, despite the fact that I have done mvn install:install-file

Comment: Could you please post your exact `mvn install:install-file` command with all parameters

Comment: `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=src/phidget21.jar -DgroupId=com -DartifactId=phidgets -Dversion=2.1 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true`

Comment: Looks about right. Did the jar file make its way to `~/.m2/repository/com/phidgets/2.1/` ?

Comment: Yes, I double-checked too.

Comment: Ok, so assuming that your dependency is installed correctly, can you post the output from your exec Maven command?

Comment: I ran with mvn `exec:java -Dexec.classpathScope=system -Dexec.mainClass=<path>`. The PhidgetSensorNode is the main application. I checked all spellings and paths. Here is the output.                                                                    `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.hypower.gatech.phidget.PhidgetSensorNode`

Comment: Prior to the `exec:java` command, did you run `mvn compile` ?

Comment: Yes. I even did `mvn clean` and `mvn compile` again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93250/discussion-between-user3727610-and-daniel).